# null reference checking in CLR

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Some questions about null reference checking by the CLR in C#

Consider this:

```
class CS
{
  public int X;
}

void Foo(CS c)
{
  c.X += 10;
}

CS c = default(CS);

Foo(c);
```

obviously a NullReferenceException is thrown here.

Now CS becomes a struct

```
struct CS { public int X; }

CS c = default(CS);

Foo(c);
```

Now no exception is thrown

Then Foo is changed into taking a ref CS cs argument.

```
void Foo(ref CS c) { c.X += 10; }
```

Again no exception since CS is still a struct.

Now the questions.

1. Does the CLR generate an "if (x == null)" statement for every field reference of class objects or how does it do that?
2. Does the CLR do the same for ref arguments when the argument is a struct?
3. Is it possible to get null for the CS argument when CS is a struct?

Comment: struct is value type so it cannot be null

Comment: I believe the "null-checking" happens because the process has to get the address of your data in memory, and there you have your null. Because of that null you can't get your data and so the NullReferenceException is thrown.

Comment: Even when the questions are along the same line you should try to formulate 1 question that covers everything. If you look at the answers here they don't all answer all of your questions, in the end it may be hard for you to accept a single answer to your question because you asked multiple questions.

Comment: @Lasse truetrue. next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structs are **value types**, so they aren't null. (You'd have to make it a `Nullable<CS>` since value types can't be null - see [Nullable docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

`default(CS)` is a struct where `X` (another value type) is `0` (or more precisely, `default(int)`). All Fields in a struct are initialized to `default(FieldType)`.

For more information about structs, check out [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your questions:

1. The act of dereferencing a reference to get to a member will throw the exception. No *explicit* or * implicit* if-statement is added but the effect is the same.
2. No, it does not. A `struct` variable can never be null. The compiler knows this.
3. No, a `ref struct X` parameter can never be null, you're not referencing the struct you're referencing the variable holding the struct. You can't compile code that references no variable when calling that method, hence no need.

If you were to use pointers, then yes, nulls can occur even with pointers to structs, but not with `ref` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Because `struct` in C# is a `value-type`, it cannot be `null`. You can use `Nullable<YourStruct>` and then use `HasValue` property to check if it's just initialized.
And a struct is always initialized. if not by you, then by the compiler with default values.